# How do I know when a pushed ViewController gets popped?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, segue

I am using segues to push a `ViewController`. This works fine. But how can I catch the situation that the `ViewController` gets popped? More precisely when the user presses "back" in the `NavigationBar`?

Is there a delegate method for this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007662-CH3-SW2) for the controller down in the stack i.e. the one that will show after popping. Maybe that's the one residing in the `self.parentViewController` pointer, just check it.